# Trying to open unknown but simple looking (just geometry) ascii 3d model file.txt in blender

Tags: import

So I have this weird .txt file for a really old game project. I don't know what kind of file it is but it is a text file (.txt). It contains stuff like this. It should be 3d model in some weird txt format... ascii something? I'm sure it is some kind of existing file format but I don't know what it is called. All I remember is that I saved the file as a backup some 15 years ago. The file seems to only contain geometry of the mesh (vertices).

2.000000
166
452
X: -349.039856
Y: 25.686975
Z: 28.132673
C: FF5777A1
X: -346.128082
Y: 21.734615
Z: 27.500698
C: FF5777A1
X: -344.545929
Y: 19.567871
Z: 25.994253
C: FF5777A1
X: -343.364471
Y: 17.949909
Z: 23.516270
C: FF5777A1
X: -342.886230
Y: 17.294985
Z: 20.678743
C: FF5777A1
X: -342.886230
Y: 17.294985
Z: 9.678737
C: FF5D7CA6
X: -342.886230
Y: 17.294985
Z: 3.678736
C: FF5D7CA6
X: -342.886230
Y: 17.294985
Z: 0.678359
C: FFCCEBFF
X: -345.812744
Y: 21.328114
Z: 29.460487
C: FF7392BC
X: -349.039856
Y: 25.686975
Z: 30.247604
C: FF7392BC
X: -343.681366
Y: 18.510126
Z: 27.357716
C: FF7190BA
X: -342.323212
Y: 16.458624
Z: 24.520267
C: FF7190BA

...and so forth. The ending is like this:
X: -366.034607
Y: 21.981529
Z: 1.920586
C: FFCBEAFF

The actual .txt file is couple of megs. Does anyone recognize what kind of file it is and how to open it in blender? Could it be point cloud data of some kind? I'm assuming the c: xxxxxxx is some kind of mesh or face identifying tag because it is repeated a lot in the file... maybe so it knows to which mesh or face each vertice belongs? Because the file is so old I think all meshes are either triangles or quads. No n-gons.

I don't know how to write python script so I can't write my own file importer. But if I knew what is the name of the file format I could probably find a blender importer or find some other software than can open it...

edit
So I managed to create a "decoder" in libre office from this file. Is there any file format that blender can open that accepts something like this for example:
42.5345, 5.2342, 88.456
43.5345, 8.2342, 88.456
46.7345, 12.2342, 88.333
...
Basically a simple list of vertices like this:
 x,y,z
 x,y,z
 x,y,z

I'd be happy with anything at this point...

Comment: You could use Animation Nodes to parse the text file and plot the vertices. Node setup wouldn't be too complex.